# IllegalArg Vs null check

Tags: java

If I have a class like

```
class A
{
   Private B b;

   X getX()
   {
      X x = b.newClient().call(); 
   }

}
```

Here should I be checking if b is null ? How should this be handled ? Using exceptions (for e.g. this isnt really an argument so does throwing an illegalArgument make sense here ? or simply logging an error ?

Comment: really depends on what B is and its business logic,  sometimes it would be safe to check for null and to create, other times this would not make sense.

Comment: If `b` is `null`, someone forgot to initialize it in a way that made sense.  If the initialization of `b` can return `null`,  then you have a few other issues instead.  (Your attack point would be the troublesome initialization.)

Answer (score 1):

`private B b` is part of your hidden, internal implementation (i.e. It's not part of the public API, used by clients of your class).  So it's not a client's problem that `b` is null, it's *your* problem, as the developer of the class.

---

Imagine if you were trying to use some shiny new library you got off GitHub:

```
MagicAnythingParser parser = new MagicAnythingParser();
parser.parse(myDocument);
```

and the call to `parse` threw an exception that said `"intakeManifold is null"`.  You'd be thinking "What the hell?!"

Little did you know, that you were *expected* to first make a call like:

```
parser.setupParseRules(someRuleset);
```

and internally, this created some object and assigned it to `intakeManifold`.

A much better scenario would be, if `MagicAnythingParser` did a good job of tracking its internal state, and instead threw something like an `IllegelStateException("No parse rules applied. You must call setupParseRules first.")`

---

My whole point is, you should develop the public API of your classes, with the clients in mind (even if that client is you.) Try to ensure that your objects are always in a "good state" - and when you cannot, throw meaningful exceptions, that make it *blindingly obvious* what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strategy for handling the possibility of a null pointer? I.e. if the variable should NEVER be null, and therefore indicates a bug, then you might not want to hide it. I'm a fan of letting the system blow up in my face so that the fault is found quickly and the root cause determined easily.

If your code is designed to carry on anyway, for example when processing batches and you don't want one fault in a batch item to kill the whole batch, then you can log it or whatever. But otherwise just let the NPE do it's thing.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if *b* is null in *getX* does not buy you much.  You are trading one runtime exception for another.  You really want to know why *b* is null.

I would recommend making *b* final and setting it through the constructor.  Perform your null check in the constructor.